# Logical operators in SPD2013 (nested and / or operators)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow2013

I have a SP2013 list, which has 2 mandatory fields "Team" and "Client" that allows you to select:
1. Team (A, B, C; etc. until Team P) and
2. Client (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3; etc. until P1, P2, P3)

Clients A1, A2, A3 can only be selected with Team A
B1, B2, B3 - with Team B
C1, C2, C3 - with Team C; etc. (until team P)

How do I use logical operators in SharePoint Designer 2013 - Workflow Designer to get the following result:
If: Team A and Client: A1 or A2 or A3, then: email to Team A,
If: Team B and Client: B1 or B2 or B3, then: email to Team B,
If: Team C and Client: C1 or C2 or C3, then: email to Team C,
(until Team P & email to Team P)

The end result should always be an email to one of the Teams: A to P.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: As the Team and Client are mandatory the mapping selection will be inserted before start the workflow. E.g. If Team is A the Client will definitely come with A1 or A2 or A3. Am I right? or this condition should be in workflow before send an email?

Comment: This is the current idea. However, management team will be considering reallocation of the clients, so eventually it may happen that for Team A, Client B2 will be allocated. Should've mentioned this as well. 
The list is supposed to serve as a query management tool, with emails being triggered by change of the query status (New, Replied, Closed). Emails will only be triggered with status New and status Replied.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the Logic IN a SharePoint Designer workflow.. takes some clicking

It is easier to write a Calculated Column Formula and then have your Workflow continue with that

In Calculated Columns the Logical Operators are Functions

So OR is:

```
OR( Client="A1" , Client="A2" , Client="A3" )
```

But it is shorter to use a String operation:

```
LEFT(Client,1)="A"
```

Your logic of Teams A to P can be written as:

```
Team = LEFT(Client,1)
```

eg:

"A" = "A"

So there is either an Email to a Team ... or No Email

Create a Calculated Column `MailToTeam` with Formula:

```
=IF( Team=LEFT(Client,1) , Team , "NoMail" )
```

And then use that in your SPD Workflow

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for the above. The issue is that calculated columns allow nesting of up to 7 "Ifs" (at least as per one of the forums related to SP2013) and with Teams A-P the number of "Ifs" exceeds that. I was more hoping for applying the "Else-If Branch" in SPD2013 but I have difficulties in getting the logic in correctly. 
Also, I need to get these emails working both ways: 
1. To specific team allocated to specific client who's gonna resolve query (triggered by query status "NEW"). 
2. Secondly to the user who logged query (triggered by query status "REPLIED").
Does this make sense?

Comment: That one line Formula is **all** you need for your A to Z use-cases